# Regex to accept anything in url django

Tags: python, regex, django

I am trying to have a url that accept anything passed in the url parameters but when i am trying it says Http 301 redirect..

> my url is /reply/?agent_type=web&input=anything

and my regex for this in django url  is

> url(ur'^reply/(.*)/$', views.visit),

Comment: your current regex has a trailing slash at the end.  Does `/reply/?agent_type=web&input=anything/` work?  or `url(ur'^reply/(.*)$', views.visit)` for the regex?

Comment: Would you be so kind as to mark the answer as correct in keeping with the usual practice here at stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Your regex basically says

```
 reply/something here/
```

or 
     reply//

Hence the reason that you are getting the redirect. Easiest thing is probablly to use two url patterns here or

```
url(ur'^reply/(.*)/?$', views.visit),
```

But the above has the undesirable side effect of links without trailing slashes not being directed to the version with the trailing slash

Answer (score 0):

Those inputs are `get` parameters, and you don't need to match them in a url - if anything matching them in a url would make it harder for yourself since you'd then need to parse them in a view yourself.

Instead just  change your url to just the `/reply/` and lookup all the get parameters in the `request.GET` dictionary in the view

```
url(ur'^reply/$', views.visit),

dev visit(request):
    anything = request.GET['input']
    agent_type = request.GET.get('agent_type')
```